# Regex to get the file extension

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list which contains file names (without their full path)

```
List<string> list=new List<string>();

list.Add("File1.doc");
list.Add("File2.pdf");
list.Add("File3.xls");

foreach(var item in list) {
    var val=item.Split('.');
    var ext=val[1];
}
```

I don't want to use `String.Split`, how will I get the extension of the file with regex?

Comment: Why not use Path.GetExtension? Regex is overkill here if you only want the extension.

Comment: to get the right ext var ext =val[1]; can better be: var ext =val[val.Length-1];, your current code has better performance as a regex or any other method if you start with a string.

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to use regex for that. You can use [`Path.GetExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) method.

> Returns the extension of the specified path string.

```
string name = "notepad.exe";
string ext = Path.GetExtension(name).Replace(".", ""); // exe
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/Tw2QEF).

Answer (score 6):

To get the extension using regex:

```
foreach (var item in list) {
    var ext = Regex.Match( item, "[^.]+$" ).Value;
}
```

Or if you want to make sure there is a dot:

```
@"(?<=\.)[^.]+$"
```

Comment: `(?<=\.)[^.]+$` is perfect!

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Path.GetExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx).

Example (also removes the dot):

```
string filename  = "MyAwesomeFileName.ext";
string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename).Replace(".", ""); 

// extension now contains "ext"
```

Comment: i don't have full file path.

Answer (score 3):

The regex is

```
\.([A-Za-z0-9]+)$
```

Escaped period, 1 or more alpha-numeric characters, end of string

---

You could also use LastIndexOf(".")

```
int delim = fileName.LastIndexOf(".");
string ext = fileName.Substring(delim >= 0 ? delim : 0);
```

---

But using the built in function is always more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of googlers -

I was dealing with bizarre filenames e.g. FirstPart.SecondPart.xml, with the extension being unknown.

In this case, Path.GetFileExtension() got confused by the extra dots.

The regex I used was

```
\.[A-z]{3,4}$
```

i.e. match the last instance of 3 or 4 characters with a dot in front only. You can test it here at [Regexr](http://regexr.com?35kbh). Not a prize winner, but did the trick.

The obvious flaw is that if the second part were 3-4 chars and the file had no extension, it would pick that up, however I knew that was not a situation I would encounter.

Comment: This will solve that too - `\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

Answer (score 0):

`"\\.[^\\.]+"` matches anything that starts with `.` character followed by 1 or more no `.` characters.

By the way the others are right, regex is overkill here.